# Writing a bash script that removes every line of text not beginning with x, y, or z

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a bash script that goes through a text file, *TextInput.txt*, and remove every line of text that doesn't start with *s1*, *s2* ... *sN* (where *sX* is a single- or multi-character string; in the example below, I'll go with 'Rabbit', 'Squirrel', and 'Puppy' as accepted starts of lines). It should then write everything to a new text file, *TextOutput.txt*.

Being no to bash scripting, I've only managed to write this fairly limited dummy code.

```
#!/bin/sh
TextInput=$(<TextInput.txt)
AcceptedStrings[0]='Rabbit'
AcceptedStrings[1]='Squirrel'
AcceptedStrings[2]='Puppy'

# What goes here?

echo "$TextModified" > TextOutput.txt
```

Comment: You might try `egrep`: `egrep "^(s1|s2|...|sN)" TextInput.txt > TextModified.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the strings are specified on the command line, you can loop through them using `grep -v`.  If you already know all the strings, you can do `egrep -v ^(str1|str2|str3) filename`.

Reading your question again, you said that you want to remove lines that don't start with the specified string but in the example, you gave a list of accepted strings.  You may need to clarify on that.

Comment: "you said that you want to remove lines that don't start with the specified string but in the example, you gave a list of accepted strings" - Isn't this, in essence, the same thing?

Comment: Well, I read it as the list of strings that will be accepted as beginning of line.  Now I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20218187/writing-a-bash-script-that-removes-every-line-of-text-not-beginning-with-x-y-o#comment30148568_20218187) above, you could use `grep`.  However, if you wanted to do it using `bash`, you could say:

```
acceptedstring=( Rabbit Squirrel Puppy )
pattern=$( IFS=$'|'; echo "${acceptedstring[*]}" )
while read -r line; do
 [[ "$line" =~ ^($pattern) ]] || echo "$line"
done < TextInput.txt > TextOutput.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

First convert your array of accepting strings into a pattern and then use `grep` to find all the lines which match the pattern:

```
pattern=$(printf "|%s" "${AcceptedStrings[@]}")
pattern=${pattern:1}

grep "^($pattern)" TextInput.txt > TextOutput.txt
```